# Unable to Read BME280 using TM4C123 LaunchPAD

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, tm4c123g

I'm new to the Tiva Platform for the past two days I'm trying to read data from bme280's data registers. However, it always returns a  0(I2C bus not working). So far I've tried using this sensor with Arduino and it works perfectly fine.

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/uart.h"
#include "driverlib/i2c.h"
#include "utils/uartstdio.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include "bme280.h"
#include "bme280_defs.h"
int8_t stream_sensor_data_normal_mode(struct bme280_dev *dev);
void print_sensor_data(struct bme280_data *comp_data);
void main()
{
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_2_5 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
    SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
    InitConsole();
    UARTprintf("UART OK \n");
    InitI2C1();
    UARTprintf("I2C OK \n");
    struct bme280_dev dev;
    int8_t rslt = BME280_OK;
    dev.dev_id = 0x77;
    dev.intf = BME280_I2C_INTF;
    dev.read = user_i2c_read;
    dev.write = user_i2c_write;
    dev.delay_ms = user_delay_ms;
    rslt = bme280_init(&dev);
    stream_sensor_data_normal_mode(&dev);
}

int8_t stream_sensor_data_normal_mode(struct bme280_dev *dev)
{
    int8_t rslt;
    uint8_t settings_sel;
    struct bme280_data comp_data;

    /* Recommended mode of operation: Indoor navigation */
    dev->settings.osr_h = BME280_OVERSAMPLING_1X;
    dev->settings.osr_p = BME280_OVERSAMPLING_16X;
    dev->settings.osr_t = BME280_OVERSAMPLING_2X;
    dev->settings.filter = BME280_FILTER_COEFF_16;
    dev->settings.standby_time = BME280_STANDBY_TIME_62_5_MS;

    settings_sel = BME280_OSR_PRESS_SEL;
    settings_sel |= BME280_OSR_TEMP_SEL;
    settings_sel |= BME280_OSR_HUM_SEL;
    settings_sel |= BME280_STANDBY_SEL;
    settings_sel |= BME280_FILTER_SEL;
    rslt = bme280_set_sensor_settings(settings_sel, dev);
    rslt = bme280_set_sensor_mode(BME280_NORMAL_MODE, dev);

    UARTprintf("Temperature, Pressure, Humidity\r\n");
    while (1) {
        /* Delay while the sensor completes a measurement */
        dev->delay_ms(1000);
        rslt = bme280_get_sensor_data(BME280_ALL, &comp_data, dev);
        print_sensor_data(&comp_data);
    }

    return rslt;
}

void print_sensor_data(struct bme280_data *comp_data)
{
#ifdef BME280_FLOAT_ENABLE
        UARTprintf("%0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f\r\n",comp_data->temperature, comp_data->pressure, comp_data->humidity);
#else
        UARTprintf("%l, %l, %l\r\n",comp_data->temperature, comp_data->pressure, comp_data->humidity);
#endif
}



void InitConsole(void)
{
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable (SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
    GPIOPinConfigure (GPIO_PA0_U0RX);
    GPIOPinConfigure (GPIO_PA1_U0TX);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable (SYSCTL_PERIPH_UART0);
    UARTClockSourceSet(UART0_BASE, UART_CLOCK_SYSTEM);
    GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1);
    UARTStdioConfig(0, 115200, SysCtlClockGet());
}

void InitI2C1(void)
{
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable (SYSCTL_PERIPH_I2C1);
    GPIOPinTypeI2C(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7);
    GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6);
    GPIOPinConfigure (GPIO_PA6_I2C1SCL);
    GPIOPinConfigure (GPIO_PA7_I2C1SDA);
    I2CMasterInitExpClk(I2C1_BASE, SysCtlClockGet(), false);
}

void I2CSend(uint8_t slave_addr, uint8_t num_of_args, ...)
{   int i;
    // Tell the master module what address it will place on the bus when
    // communicating with the slave.
    I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C1_BASE, slave_addr, false);

    //stores list of variable number of arguments
    va_list vargs;

    //specifies the va_list to "open" and the last fixed argument
    //so vargs knows where to start looking
    va_start(vargs, num_of_args);

    //put data to be sent into FIFO
    I2CMasterDataPut(I2C1_BASE, va_arg(vargs, uint32_t));

    //if there is only one argument, we only need to use the
    //single send I2C function
    if (num_of_args == 1)
    {
        //Initiate send of data from the MCU
        I2CMasterControl(I2C1_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_SINGLE_SEND);

        // Wait until MCU is done transferring.
        while (I2CMasterBusy(I2C1_BASE))
            ;

        //"close" variable argument list
        va_end(vargs);
    }

    //otherwise, we start transmission of multiple bytes on the
    //I2C bus
    else
    {
        //Initiate send of data from the MCU
        I2CMasterControl(I2C1_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_BURST_SEND_START);

        // Wait until MCU is done transferring.
        while (I2CMasterBusy(I2C1_BASE))
            ;

        //send num_of_args-2 pieces of data, using the
        //BURST_SEND_CONT command of the I2C module
        for (i = 1; i < (num_of_args - 1); i++)
        {
            //put next piece of data into I2C FIFO
            I2CMasterDataPut(I2C1_BASE, va_arg(vargs, uint32_t));
            //send next data that was just placed into FIFO
            I2CMasterControl(I2C1_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_BURST_SEND_CONT);

            // Wait until MCU is done transferring.
            while (I2CMasterBusy(I2C1_BASE))
                ;
        }

        //put last piece of data into I2C FIFO
        I2CMasterDataPut(I2C1_BASE, va_arg(vargs, uint32_t));
        //send next data that was just placed into FIFO
        I2CMasterControl(I2C1_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_BURST_SEND_FINISH);
        // Wait until MCU is done transferring.
        while (I2CMasterBusy(I2C1_BASE))
            ;

        //"close" variable args list
        va_end(vargs);
    }
}

void user_delay_ms(uint32_t period)
{
    SysCtlDelay((SysCtlClockGet() / 1000) * (uint32_t) period);
}

int8_t user_i2c_read(uint8_t dev_id, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data,
                     uint16_t len)
{
    int8_t rslt = 0; /* Return 0 for Success, non-zero for failure */
    /*
     * The parameter dev_id can be used as a variable to store the I2C address of the device
     */

    /*
     * Data on the bus should be like
     * |------------+---------------------|
     * | I2C action | Data                |
     * |------------+---------------------|
     * | Start      | -                   |
     * | Write      | (reg_addr)          |
     * | Stop       | -                   |
     * | Start      | -                   |
     * | Read       | (reg_data[0])       |
     * | Read       | (....)              |
     * | Read       | (reg_data[len - 1]) |
     * | Stop       | -                   |
     * |------------+---------------------|
     */
    I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C1_BASE, (uint8_t) dev_id, false);
    I2CMasterDataPut(I2C1_BASE, (uint8_t) reg_addr);
    I2CMasterControl(I2C1_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_BURST_SEND_START);
    while (I2CMasterBusy (I2C1_BASE))
        ;
    I2CMasterControl(I2C1_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_BURST_SEND_FINISH);
    I2CMasterSlaveAddrSet(I2C1_BASE, dev_id, true);
    while (len--)
    {
        I2CMasterControl(I2C1_BASE, I2C_MASTER_CMD_BURST_RECEIVE_START);
        while (I2CMasterBusy (I2C1_BASE))
            ;
        *reg_data = I2CMasterDataGet(I2C1_BASE);
        reg_data++;
    }
    return rslt;
}

int8_t user_i2c_write(uint8_t dev_id, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data,
                      uint16_t len)
{
    int8_t rslt = 0; /* Return 0 for Success, non-zero for failure */

    /*
     * The parameter dev_id can be used as a variable to store the I2C address of the device
     */

    /*
     * Data on the bus should be like
     * |------------+---------------------|
     * | I2C action | Data                |
     * |------------+---------------------|
     * | Start      | -                   |
     * | Write      | (reg_addr)          |
     * | Write      | (reg_data[0])       |
     * | Write      | (....)              |
     * | Write      | (reg_data[len - 1]) |
     * | Stop       | -                   |
     * |------------+---------------------|
     */
    I2CSend(dev_id,1,reg_addr);
    while(len--)
    {
       I2CSend(dev_id,1,*reg_data);
       reg_data++;

    }

}
```

Comment: Use an oscilloscope or logic analyzer to view what is happening on the clock and data lines.

Comment: @kkrambo: Hooked up an oscilloscope both SDA and SCL remain high(No switching) throughout the code. Maybe an initialization issue but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

You are not configuring the I2C Pins.

From the source file GPIO.c

```
//! \note This function cannot be used to turn any pin into an I2C SDA pin; it
//! only configures an I2C SDA pin for proper operation.  Note that a
//! GPIOPinConfigure() function call is also required to properly configure a
//! pin for the I2C SDA function.
```

There is a similar statement about the clock pin.

So you need to add the following two lines:

```
GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA6_I2C1SCL);

GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA7_I2C1SDA);
```

Comment: Added those two lines still no luck!

Comment: Have you read through Chapter 16 in the manual?

Comment: Which manual? Are you talking about the Workshop lab manual?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c123gh6pm.pdf

Comment: I don't see where you initialize the SCL Clock speed.

Comment: There are also three example projects in the TivaWare examples.

Comment: I got the I2C reading part working. However, I2C write is still not working(nothing on the oscilloscope).

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your updated code where you try to write anything.